# Como proteger rutas automáticamente en Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-security

estoy usando Spring Security para la seguridad de mi aplicación web y cada ruta la tengo que definir en la configuración de Security.
Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma en que la aplicación solicite loguearse cuando quiera ingresar a cualquier página de mi aplicación sin tener que definir la ruta en el Spring Config, ya que tal vez por error me olvide de colocar una y el usuario podrá hacer y deshacer cosas sin la necesidad de estar logueado.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM') or hasRole('ROLE_VENDEDOR')") 
    .antMatchers("/usuarios").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM')")
    .antMatchers("/ventas").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM') or hasRole('ROLE_VENDEDOR')")
    .antMatchers("/reportes").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADM')")
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("password")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/denied");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto para que todas las rutas solicite que este autenticado el usuario:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```